# Convert IQueryable<IEnumerable<Entity>> to IQueryable<Entity>

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have the query which return the last UserBattle record for every user:

```
objectContext.UserBattles.
GroupBy(bu => bu.UserId, bu => bu).
Select(gbu => gbu.OrderByDescending(bu => bu.DateTime).First());
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work (at least MySQL .NET Connector provider can't convert `First` to SQL). As alternative I can replace First call by `Take(1)`. But unfortunately in this case the result will be `IQueryable<IEnumerable<UserBattle>>` instead of `IQueryable<UserBattle>`. Is there any way to get `IQueryable<UserBattle>` without going to LINQ To Objects (for example, SelectMany would solve my problem).

Comment: try .SingleOrDefault(), that the method for what you want

Comment: What's the problem with going to LINQ to Objects if you're only selecting one record?

Comment: @Bertrand Marron, one for each user

Comment: Did you try `FirstOrDefault`? `First`, `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` all are **not supported** in a projection, even not with SQL Server.

Comment: @Slauma, I tried it - doesn't work

Comment: Oh, then it must indeed be a limitation in the MySQL Connector. `FirstOrDefault` works with the Provider for SQL Server.

Comment: @Slauma. MySQL .NET Connector is very buggy... Please provide your comment as an answer - I will accept it

Comment: @Idsa: I've merged the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` work all as the *finishing* method of a LINQ to Entities query (as "greedy" operators at the end which cause the query to execute).

However **in a projection (Select(...)) only `FirstOrDefault` is supported**.

That's the case for the .NET Provider for SQL Server. If your query even doesn't work with `FirstOrDefault` then it's most likely a limitation of the MySQL .NET Connector (by design or as a bug?).

Just to mention for completeness: `Last` and `LastOrDefault` are not supported at all in LINQ to Entities, neither as finishing methods nor in a projection. That's the reason why your Select expression must be written as `gbu => gbu.OrderByDescending(bu => bu.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()`. The logical identical expression `gbu => gbu.OrderBy(bu => bu.DateTime).LastOrDefault()` is possible in LINQ to Objects but not in LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

try .SingleOrDefault(), that the method for what you want

Comment: Unfortunately neigther SingleOrDefault nor FirstOrDefault are converter to SQL (exception is raised). I guess it is a problem of MySQL .NET Connector provider